# How to include all variables into regression by manual function?

Tags: r, regression, panel

I want to include all variables into panel regression, however I have some queries how it can be done (`~.` is not working for panel regressions).

```
library(plm)
data("Produc", package="plm")
varnames<-names(Produc)[5:length(Produc)]
exp <- paste0(varnames,collapse='+')
plm(as.formula(pcap~exp),data='Produc')
```

And I see error

```
Error in if (!id.name %in% names(x)) stop(paste("variable ", id.name,  : 
  argument is of length zero
```

It seem's like it's not recognized but I don't have idea why. Could you please help me solving this issue ?

Comment: Can't you just do `plm(pcap ~ ., data = Produc[, <columns you want to include>])`?

Comment: plm() function does not support ~. - after using this folloiwng error occurs : Error in terms.formula(object) : '.' in formula and no 'data' argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixes your approach:

```
library(plm)
data("Produc", package="plm")
varnames<-names(Produc)[5:length(Produc)]
exp <- paste0(varnames,collapse='+')
f <- paste0("pcap ~", exp)
plm(as.formula(f),data=Produc)
```